# Getting a new (separate) instance of an object that is registered as "per request"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have a service (in this case, a database context wrapper) that is registered with my SimpleInjector container as "per request", meaning that anything that I inject into will get the same instance within the scope of a request.

This is working great for standard logic, but I have a requirement to get a new instance of the db context for a specific part of the code.

Is there a way with SimpleInjector to request a "new" instance, despite being in the same "per request" scope? I don't want to `new` up an instance manually.

Thanks

Comment: Could the wrapper implement two interfaces? Register one as per request and one as transient. When you need a transient, inject the second interface rather than the first.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection

Comment: Can you add some code that demonstrates this?

Comment: @mjwills, thanks for the suggestion. We ended up taking your suggested approach as it seemed neater than having separate conditional IOC setups that would have to change in each place we needed a different instance